# How can I uniformly chop peanuts?

Tags: nuts, cutting, peanuts

I'd love to get something approximating the nicely uniform chopped peanuts you get when you order a sundae at McDonald's.

I have tried manually chopping the nuts, and they come out all sorts of shapes and sizes.  I bought a manual nut chopper, and while this is closer, there's still lots of peanut dust.

Short of buying a commercial nut chopper, is there any trick to get the nuts chopped evenly and with minimal dust?

Comment: wear an apron and chef's hat

Comment: Use a sieve to remove the dust. A wire mesh kitchen strainer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the commercial choppers used for McDonald's nuts generate the same amount of dust. They probably sell that dust for some other purpose.

The dust should be easy enough to remove: just shake them around in a strainer.

Comment: I did consider that idea as I was typing the question; thanks for writing it out :)

Comment: I've bought 'pecan meal' before, which I suspect is the leftovers from a similar process.

Answer (score 4):

As @Carey Gregory already mentioned about McDonald's, I generally cook for 6-10 people and for small kitty and birthday parties, so for that I use a manual nut chopper (with size adjustment bolt).  This gives me fine results of chopped nuts almost in equal shapes. For 2-5 servings, I simply use a sharp knife to chop them. I almost every time try to make them uniformly chopped. But obviously it's a time taking process, but you can do it if you are preparing for 3-5 servings. You can purchase the nut chopper with size adjustment bolt for much better result.

Comment: I bet a coffee grinder would also do the trick.